# On the fly augmentation for segmentation

Tags: keras, pytorch, image-segmentation, data-augmentation

Hi I am trying to do 2D prostate segmentation using U-net. I want to apply data augmentation to both prostate and label images (X,y), for this I am currently using Torch.io which applies the same random tranformation to both label and data itself. My problem is I cannot load all the augmented data to RAM thus want to do on-the-fly augmentation. Any ideas how can I directly feed the transformed data to my u-net network ???? Thanks.

Comment: Fyi, I can not use Keras ImageDataGenerator since it only transforms the data and not label!

Answer (score 0):

You should look at libraries such as [albuminations](https://albumentations.ai/) that extend the `torchvision.transforms` to work also on segmentation masks etc.

Comment: yes I looked it up but my problem is not augmenting the mask. I already did augment both mask and data but I cant feed it into my network. How do i put it to network like on-fly method?

Comment: if you put the augmentations as part of your `Dataset`'s `__getitem__` method - it will augment the data on-the-fly as it loads it for training/validation.

Comment: Sorry for my rookie question but im new at this :/ I am using keras layers and dont know how to edit the builtin getitem method. Should I re define the function and implement augmentation inside the function ?

Comment: @Beg I'm more of a pytorch kind of guy. I'm not familiar with these details of keras. Why did you tag your question "pytorch" if you are using keras?

Comment: I thought if there are pytorch suggestions ı could switch the model.